# Angularjs sorting based on start date and end date?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

all I want to filter the items like (Start and End Date)  which are based on `invoice_date` using the date range functionality in meanjs app.

- My problem is the date filter function are working perfectly in `plunker and my localHost production` but  while pushing to server it's showing only up to `May month` data's if some `invoice_date` values date is been `2017-08-24 and 2017-07-27' these data is not displaying in table, I don't know where I did the mistake and what I have missed it ..... [My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/25sDpSmciSfQ7nC7x1a7?p=preview)
- Please look at my plunker to reference.
- I Have displaying `invoice_date`, so this is the field I want to use for filtering.
- So what I exactly looking for, I want to filter the `invoice_date` as start date and end date : **for example:-** if we select start date like `24-05-2017` and end date is `24-08-2017` in table this two transaction only need to display or filter... so I have used date range filter to achieve this solution, but in server it's not working for us please help.
- In my server if I select `end date` as today's date all data's are showing on the table, so I think the problem is based on these fields `$scope.from = new Date(2014, 04, 30);
  $scope.to = new Date(2019, 08, 25);`
- **There are two solutions**:- 
  (i) if we set `end date` as a today's date default in date range function all data's are showing perfectly.
- (ii) [image] in terminal this error occurs if we solve this error definitely will get the solution, I have tried it myself but I unable to solve this... so please help to solve this problem.

**Controller:**

```
 .filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, dateKey, from, to) {
        return records.filter(function(record) {
            return !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isBefore(moment(from))
            && !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isAfter(moment(to));
        });
    };
})
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to">
```

**Filter:-**

```
ng-repeat="data in  record | dateRange : 'invoice_date' : from : to"
```

- I have created plunker for reference:- [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/25sDpSmciSfQ7nC7x1a7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the moment.js in your project.
If not then try to include it.

```
npm install moment --save   # npm
yarn add moment             # Yarn
Install-Package Moment.js   # NuGet
spm install moment --save   # spm
meteor add momentjs:moment  # meteor
bower install moment --save # bower (deprecated)
```